# Passing C++ vector to method results in unresolved externals

Tags: c++, vector

I've looked at a ton of examples and I don't know what I'm doing wrong. I can't pass a vector as a parameter or the compiler says unresolved externals.

Here's an example that doesn't work for me:

In the .h:

```
#include <vector>

void VectorTest(std::vector<std::string> & vect);
```

In the .cpp:

```
void VectorTest(std::vector<std::string> & vect)
{

}
```

Also in the .cpp, in a method where I'm trying to call it:

```
std::vector<std::string> test;
VectorTest(test);
```

When I compile I get the error:
error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals

If I comment out

```
VectorTest(test);
```

It builds. I'm still learning C++ so it's probably something obvious. I'm using Visual Studio Express 2013 if that matters.

On a Yahoo! Answers someone posted this example and it does not work for me, same error:

```
void myfunc( std::vector<int>& vec ) 
{ 
} 

std::vector<int> vec; 
myfunc( vec );
```

Here's the error (trying to use the myfunc shown above):

```
error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: void __thiscall trackManager::myfunc(class std::vector<int,class std::allocator<int> > &)" (?myfunc@trackManager@@QAEXAAV?$vector@HV?$allocator@H@std@@@std@@@Z) referenced in function "public: __thiscall trackManager::trackManager(void)" (??0trackManager@@QAE@XZ)
```

Comment: What is the name of that unresolved external?

Comment: Where do you `#include <string>`?

Comment: When posting questions about code that results in errors, you should really include the actual errors in the question. However, it sound to me like you're not building with the source file where the function is defined in.

Comment: Sounds like you are not linking against the C++ runtime?

Comment: Did you include the header file in the .cpp file?

Comment: String include is in .h and .cpp includes the .h. My other methods/function (whatever you call it in C++) work, it's just when I added this one it doesn't for some reason. I updated it to include the error line.

Comment: It looks like you have defined VectorTest/myFunc as a member function in the header but as a free function in the cpp.

Comment: @dlf Looks like it. Nice catch

Comment: You're right, I forgot to put trackManager:: (my class name) before it. I'm still getting used to c++. Do you want to put that as the answer and I'll accept?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you declared `VectorTest()` as a `trackManager` member function in the header but then defined it as a free function in the cpp. This results in two unrelated functions with the same name. If you try to call `VectorTest()` without qualifications from inside a `trackManager` member function, the resolver will (sensibly) prefer the version that is also a `trackManager` member over the free function. But since that one doesn't have a definition, the linker can't figure out what to do with it and you get an error.

To fix this, either move the declaration out of the body of `trackManager` (if you want it to be a free function), or write the definition as `void trackManager::VectorTest(...)` (if you want it to be a member).

Comment: VectorTest is the function name I'm trying to call. It's all in the same .h and .cpp files.

Comment: Yep, I forgot the class name before it.. newb mistake. Thanks for the help. It builds now.

Answer (score 0):

You're most likely missing the include file for string. Try to add the following line at the top of the .h file:

```
#include <string>
```

Comment: I doubt it. Shouldn't this result in a compile error, while the OP claims to get a linker error?

Comment: I believe OP mentioned that the example which just uses `int` doesn't compile either, unfortunately.

Comment: I do have that at the top of the .h file.